# Making sense ot the 3D View and aligning and rotating objects by specific values

Tags: origin

I am trying to line up a camera and a mesh in the 3D viewport.  I am having LOTS of problems.

a) I have a green line - I assume this is the X axis, though it is not labelled, same for the blue line. How do I see all three axes?

b) I set the cursor to world origin and then set my mesh to cursor, but the mesh seems to just go wherever it wants to go - and certainly not to the cursor.

c) is there a trick to navigate around the 3D space without it turning upside down or moving in an unpredictable manner?  How can I even tell if it has turned upside down?  Is there any way to move the view in a single axis at a time?  I am just usinhg my Mac trackpad with 2 fingers but it drives me crazy.

d) after selecting object I noted that the Y scale was slightly different - setting it back to 1 (same as X and Z scale caused the model to disappear altogether - I never found it again...

e) I thought that having a collection including lamp and camera might be causing Blender to snap the collection rather than just the mesh - but I moved the mesh out of the collection and it made no difference.

Really, this is driving me nuts!

f) Setting the mesh origin to cursor evidently does not move the mesh to the cursor - so how do I move the mesh itself so that it is sitting EXACTLY on all three axes?

Comment: First off, red is X axis, green is Y, Blue is Z (up, down). Secondly, I'm not sure about all the rest of the issues you're having navigating the 3d viewport, but I would HIGHLY suggest using a mouse (there are many decent usb compatible mice you can get for well under $20). It will make your life a whole lot easier. Lastly, to center an object in the "middle" of the X,Y,Z axis - in object mode press `SHIFT + S > Cursor to World Origin`, then select your object, `SHIFT + S > Selection to Cursor`.

Comment: If your object is going somewhere "on it's own", it's likely that you have offset it from it's local origin in edit mode  For example: I make a cube at world origin (0,0,0) - I enter edit mode, select the whole cube and move it 20 units along the x axis - if I do this, in object mode the cube will still be at 0,0,0, even though the cube is 20 units away from the center. This will however be shown in edit mode. This is the difference between local and global offsets. You can see the difference by pressing N and looking at your object's coordinates in both object and edit mode.

Comment: Thanks mate.  I did evebtually work out how to move the mesh once - thereafter it wouldn't move at all - I had to shut down and open a new blender window and reimport the model.

I still can't align the camera to an axis - there are many ways to move the camera but I will be rotating three models and I need the camera to be perfectly aligned on the X and Y axes and I can't find any way to do that...

I used a 3 button mouse before, but it drove me crazy just the same... :-(

I never get the Y axis displayed !

Answer (score 0):

dI solved this issue by selecting the camera and moving it to the cursor at world origin.  Then with the camera view open in another window I was able to move the camera along the X and Y axes until the model came into view (upside down!) and then rotate the camera until the model was the right way up - using the rotation properties box to specify the exact rotations - 90 / 180 / 180.

The Y axis alignment was done by eye - I could not find any way to centre the camera exactly on the centre of the model.

It will have to do...